# Exchange Server 2013 DNS Records

Tags: dns, exchange-server, portforwarding

I'm setting up DNS records on my Exchange Server 2013. I'm currently running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have purchased a web hosting package with GoDaddy and my domain name (hosted with one.com) points it's A record to it.

My Active Directory domain name is different to my external domain name. How do I set up my Exchange Server DNS records?

Note: My external domain name is danielonline.net and my AD Domain Name is dapc.local

EDIT:

> I'm very new to DNS records and Exchange server, so I need spoonfed a little - sorry

EDIT 2:

> The DNS records that I need are the ones I setup on my DNS Records page on One.com. It says I need a FQDN, a Type and a Value

EDIT 3:

> Is it even possible to create the email addresses in exchange server so that the domain part of the email is different from the AD domain? For instance, my AD domain is dom1.local - could I send & receive emails from the address: hello@dom2.com?

Comment: Just a point, I feel this would have beem more appropriate on ServerFault,  rather than SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exchange DNS Records should be setup to allow local clients to find the exchange server and connect to it.

You'll need to ensure that you configure Exchange to accept mail for the external domain; you will need to ensure that Port 25 is open for SMTP traffic in to the Exchange Server from outside, and you will need to ensure you have valid MX and A Records to point the mail correctly.

---

Based on your comments, you'll need to setup the following on your account at One.com.

```
FQDN                     Type        Value
mail.yourdomain.com      A           external IP of exchange server
yourdomain.com           MX          mail.yourdomain.com
```

An MX Record should also ask for a priority value. They are usually multiples of 10, and are used in order of lowest first. In your case, use '10' as the value.

You might see references to TTL. You can usually safely leave this as default. It means Time To Live, and is the time that this value is stored by other servers, prior to rechecking.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can find exact records? I'm very new to DNS records and Exchange server, so I need spoonfed a little - sorry :P

Comment: are you talking internal or external? Have you googled this? There are comprehensive guides on setting up exchange.

Comment: The DNS records that I need are the ones I setup on my DNS Records page on One.com. It says I need a FQDN, a Type and a Value.

Comment: For your MX Records?

Comment: Yes. I think so

Comment: Is it even possible to create the email addresses in exchange server so that the domain part of the email is different from the AD domain? For instance, my AD domain is dom1.local - could I send & receive emails from the address: hello@dom2.com?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can set the accepted mail domains in the Exchange console.

Comment: Thank you! Which MX records would I need to set up in the second domain to allow incoming and outgoing mail?

Comment: In the answer above, the same settings should apply, but altered for the new domain name. so instead of <yourdomain>, you'll need to use <yourdomain2>

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw your post edit. Yes - that should be it :) Thank you so much for your time.